# Extract rar file with SSH using php

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, import, ssh

I need to extract rar file for my custom import extension.

i have used `shell_exec()` and `exec("unzip/path/images.rar", $result, $returnval);`
but not working.

Any one knows how to extract rar file using **SSH+php**

Comment: OS on the server ?

Comment: Linux On Server

Comment: unrar is installed on the server?

Comment: Not now is this require ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Debian or Ubuntu Linux** use `apt-get`

For **Fedora Linux / CentOS / RHEL** use `yum`

Install **unrar** on server

> sudo apt-get install unrar

for zip file install **unzip**

> sudo apt-get install unzip

then try

```
exec("unrar unzip/path/images.rar");
```

for zip

```
exec("unzip path/images.zip");
```

Comment: hi can you please give me suggestion for zip also ? @gopal patel

Comment: find updated answer @denishvachhani

Comment: can you please specify how to use target to destination path in this ?

Comment: @GopalPatel perfect just replace `apt-get` to `yum` in centos

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala yeah updated sirji ;)

Comment: @denishvachhani refer http://serverfault.com/a/117534 or just google for more information about this commands because question is not related to magento

Comment: i have zip already installed in server. Need to install unzip ?

Comment: try `unzip -v` if it is installed already then it will return the version @denishvachhani

Comment: but not working

Comment: for zip its not working for rar its working fine.

Comment: make sure you are getting zip file in that directory and unzip is installed @denishvachhani

Comment: Please update your code need exec("unzip path/images.zip"); this instead of your code.

Comment: its works for me Thanks for your kind help. @GopalPatel

Comment: @denishvachhani upss sry `exec()` require string parameter. If this solve your query then mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the rar x archive.rar  command inside shell_exec().

```
shell_exec('rar x path/to/rar/file/filename.rar');
```

Make sure that path of the rar file is correct.

If the file is in the same folder where your php file is then you can give the filename without giving any path.

First, check if rar is installed in your Linux system.

if not installed, then you can run the following command -

```
sudo apt-get install rar
```